# How to declared HashMap type in C++

Tags: java, c++, hashtable

I face a problem to declare HashTable variable in C++. In java language we can declare `HashTable` variable such like

```
Hashtable<String, sqlStat>  pool = new Hashtable<String, sqlstat>(30);
```

But I try to declare `HashTable` in C++ such as the code show as below and get an error with those codes:-

```
std::unordered_map<string, sqlstmt*> abc = new std::unordered_map<string, sqlstmt*>(30);
```

I have no idea to solve this problem can anyone teach me a solution to solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: c++ is not java, dont use new if not pointing to a pointer

Comment: I'm still blur on in. Can you gv me a simple example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new` is only required for dynamic allocation, and the result is a pointer, so it would need to be assigned to a pointer variable or fed to an object that accepts a pointer. In C++, you can declare a locally scoped instance without using `new`. In your case, just leave the `new ...` out:

```
std::unordered_map<string, sqlstmt*> abc;
abc["query"] = new sqlstmt(...);
```

Coming from Java, when using dynamic allocation, you should adopt using smart pointers rather than bare pointers.

```
std::unordered_map<string, std::shared_ptr<sqlstmt> > abc;
abc["query"] = std::make_shared<sqlsmt>(...);
```

This is so you get the behavior of the memory getting reaped automatically when there are no more references to the object. Java gives you this behavior by default. In C++, you use smart pointers to get that behavior. Without smart pointers, you have to call `delete` explicitly when you are done with the dynamically allocated object.

Comment: I get an error which is 'unordered_map in namespace 'std' does not name a type.

Comment: Use a [C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map). You need to `#include <unordered_map>`.

Comment: For `shared_ptr` you need `#include <memory>`.

Comment: I have include reference to it. But it still get the same error say 'unordered_map' does not name a type.

Comment: See [this example](http://ideone.com/OVPpmD). Make sure you are compiling with C++ 11 mode.

Comment: Thank you. But I don't understand for "query" that write in abc["query"]. What we should write for query?

Comment: You are the one that wanted a map of `string` to `sqlstmt`. I just gave an example using them. Use it however you would have used it in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Just to get in touch, you need to use STL,

```
hash_map<char* key, char* value> map; //map is empty
map["a"]= "The value of a";
```

Comment: hash_map is not standard; although is common pre-C++11. C++11 has unordered_map; it was decided to rename to unordered_map as the hash_map implementations differed.